# Visual Studio Code - Python - Windows - Black runs but does not format code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I am running VS Code on Windows and am trying to set up black to format my Python code when saving. It looks like black is running whenever I save, but the file is not getting updated. When I look at the Output > Python tab in VS Code, it looks like black is running with the `--diff` flag, which is why I'm assuming that the file does not update. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my .vscode/settings.json in the project:

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\me\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black"
}
```

Comment: That's more suitable for a bug ticket, not an SO question. In any case, avoid repeating tags in the title, because it renders the title less readable.

Comment: Pro Tip: don’t use the base environment. Create a fresh environment and install the packages you need (including black)   . Use git and pre-commit. Set up black to run with pre-commit. Black is a very opinionated formatter. I prefer using autopep8 for VSCode. And black/yapf for project specific formatting.

Comment: @CypherX this is actually a fresh environment for this specific project

Comment: Did you somehow resolved this issue? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to install black package in my virtualenv. Using the one installed at the system level was not working, even though that one worked from terminal, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `--diff` has no influence on the formatting.

You can try to format it directly with black in the terminal to check whether it works or not.

If it does not work, you can try to switch to some other formatters.

Comment: When I run black directly from the terminal or via pre-commit it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (in Ubuntu though) under poetry virtual environment, and I solved by changing the black path to just "black".

I guess somehow giving a path does not operate well with the virtual environment.